# Ajax json request to stubhub not retuning json

Tags: json, ajax

I'm trying to access the stubhub API

However i cannot seem to connect to return the results as json (something i've better working inside rather than xml)

Could you have a look and see what im doing wrong?

https://api.stubhub.com/catalog/events/v3/9463762?getZones=true&wt=json

And i also have this as my headers

```
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Basic " + key);
```

And my datatype is jsonp

I can show you the rest of the code but thats basically it.

Answer (score 0):

you need this header as well (this in rails)

```
    "Accept" => "application/json"
```

so I'm guessing in ajax it would be

```
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
```